# Sharing a Class Instance Object Between React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

If I have, say, a network manager class that I have implemented with a singleton pattern.

```js
export default class Manager {
   private static _Instance: Manager;
   public static get Instance(): Manager {
      if (Manager._Instance) {
         return Manager._Instance;
      } else {
         return new Manager();
      }
   }

   constructor() {
      if (Manager._Instance) {
         return Manager._Instance;
      }
      Manager._Instance = this;
   }

   // Network management methods, etc.
}
```

And I instantiate it at the very top of my React app component tree, the beginning of the app's life cycle:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Manager from './Manager';
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
   private networkManager = new Manager();

   constructor(props: any) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           connected: false,
           id: '',
       };
   }

   componentDidMount = (): void => {
       this.initNetwork();
   };

   initNetwork = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
         // network management init and config
      } catch(err) {
         // handle network init errors 
      }
   }

   render = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            path="/foo"
                            render={(props): JSX.Element => (
                                <Foo {...props} NetworkManager={this.networkManager} />
                            )}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/"
                            render={(props): JSX.Element => <Bar {...props}/>}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
```

And I then want to use that instance in a child component, I obviously have several ways to do this, but what is the best way? I could pass it down to components as a prop, or import it and use the instance property to get the instance. Benefits and disadvantages of both approaches?

```js
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
    networkManager: Manager;
};
class Foo extends React.Component<Props> {
   private manager: Manager;
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.manager = props.networkManager;
   }
}

// alternatively in ./Bar.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Manager from './Manager';

class Bar extends React.Component {
   private manager: Manager
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.manager = Manager.Instance; // new Manager() should also return the same instance
   }
}
```

Is there another, better way to do it I'm not aware of? Something like Redux would be nice, but my experience with it is storing plain, object literals rather than class instances, and placing something like this in the store does not seem right. Does it really matter how I share the instance? Both passing down through props and importing work and are roughly equivalent in terms of amount of typing needed. Performance wise I don't think there's much of a difference either, the instance should never change and therefore the prop will never update and trigger a component re-render, but that might be something to consider. Am I overthinking it?

Comment: Why not just import the `NetworkManager` whenever you need it and instantiate it there? No need to pass it down the component tree with props...

Comment: @goto1 just wanted to know best practice, importing is definitely nicer than passing down, and the way I had originally planned on going

Comment: Not sure what this `NetworkManager` is supposed to do, but if it's something that relates to API calls then I'd just simply import it whenever I need it - passing it as a `prop` the way you have it is probably not the best way and not a good use of `props` - keep it simple. That'd be the better approach here in my opinion.

Comment: @goto1 Yes, I agree that if it was just API calls the best and simplest way is indeed just importing. But it's a little more than that, a wrapper class for opening and maintaining a connection with a server via `WebSockets`, where every new instance of the class would be a new connection over a new socket.

Comment: But it's a singleton, so this wouldn't be the case, even if you import it into multiple files and try to instantiate it multiple times, like in this example - https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-oskar-hvnlm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark.

Comment: @goto1 Yes, I implemented the Singleton pattern after the fact, because I found passing down through props cumbersome. Coming from a C# background it felt better this way, but I wanted to know if there was a “React” way of doing it

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately) `React` is not opinionated as `Angular`or `Vue` are for example, and `React` is really "just" a UI library, so this type of business logic wouldn't even fall in the "React" category. Use `props` for passing data, event handlers, and occasionally `React` components, from parent to child. The rest is really up to you.

Comment: Dislcaimer: I'm not a senior architect or anything, but I would probably opt for passing as props as this follows a more "Dependency Injection" principle. If you directly import it you're coupling yourself more to that implementation of a `NetworkManager`, whereas if you pass it is a prop it feels more like programming towards the interface.

Comment: @ehutchllew I am curious where you've seen the pattern of using `prop`s as a dependency injection

Comment: @goto1 by the fact that you can literally inject functions, classes, w/e that the component depends on via props. The component doesn't have to necessarily know about the specific implementation of this dependency, it just "uses" something on its interface.

Comment: @ehutchllew what if you need the `api` module somewhere else down your tree? do you just keep passing it via `props` through every component?

Comment: @goto1 there are options for doing that. Prop drilling to a certain extent isn't bad, but if it starts getting hairy, app state management tools can be used.

Comment: @ehutchllew prop drilling or using a state management tool for sharing an API module just to gain "dependency injection" is a tough sell for me... state management tools aren't event meant to be used in this type of way; using import statements is less problematic as you keep it as an implementation detail and there are less assumptions about how it rerenders the component

Comment: @goto1 If you know you're always going to use that same implementation, then that's fine -- it couples your code to it though. It's not a bad practice to program to an interface over an implementation.

Also, using the API module doesn't grant you dependency injection, it's your pattern that does. The API module (state management in this case) facilitates the scenario you painted above about drilling this dependency into child components.

Comment: There are pros and cons to both approaches, but at the end of the day you have to pick what will work best in the long term... My only issue with state management tools is that they're for **managing state**. You could technically share your reusable `React` components with a state management tool to prevent prop drilling, but is that a good idea?

Comment: @afryingpan I'm facing this issue now - out of curiosity, what did you end up going with?