# How to share a class instance across a react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, singleton, react-functional-component

How to share a class instance across a react application?

I need to use an external library which requires me to instantiate it and use that instance in the application to access various methods/properties,

```
const instance = new LibraryModule(someInitData);
```

I am using react functional components in my project. I don't want to re-create instance every time I need to use it (can be thought of a singleton).

How can I share the same instance with all of my components?

Comment: checkout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473706/sharing-a-class-instance-object-between-react-components

Comment: @moufed - There is no answer to it.

Comment: try as he did make  wrapper class  with static method  that returns singleton if exist  else return new instance

Answer (score 3):

Imports are already global, you just need to import the module:

```
class LibraryModule {
  x = 5;
}
const instance = new LibraryModule();

export default instance;
```

```
import instance from "./MyLibrary";
import Component from "./Component";

console.log(instance.x);

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`from App, called last`, instance.x);
  }, []);
  return <Component />;
};
```

```
import instance from "./MyLibrary";

const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    instance.x = 10;
    console.log(`from component`, instance.x);
  }, []);
  return <>Component</>;
};
```

[image: Edit fancy-https-j0s5u]

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are looking for some sort of Dependency Injection,
a thing that isn't really in the react way.

I'd suggest to use the Context Api.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

```
import React from 'react';

export const LibraryModuleContext = React.createContext(new LibraryModule);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { LibraryModuleContext } from './library-module';

const App = () => (
  <LibraryModuleContextt.Provider>
    <Toolbar />
  </LibraryModuleContext.Provider>
)
```

and then later in your code

```
import React from 'react';
import { LibraryModuleContext } from './library-module';

const FooComponent = () => {
  const LibraryModule = useContext(LibraryModuleContext);

  return (
    <div>Hello {LibraryModule.x}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: what's the benefit using context over simple class instance import as suggested in another response?